# git -- how to recover from unfinished merge

Tags: git, merge, mergetool

I started the mergetool ...

```
> git mergetool
```

And it said something like ...

```
merge tool candidates: blah blah blah
Merging:
file1.c
```

And then I thought, "You know, I'm not ready for this."  Not knowing any clean way to shut it down, I hit ctrl-C.  Now I want to check out another branch, but I can't ...

```
> git checkout other_branch
error: path 'file1.c' is unmerged
```

Is there some way to recover from this?  I emphasize that I made no actual changes when mergetool was running.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the `--abort` option which exists in most git commands:

```
git merge --abort
```

Manual entry:

> Abort the current conflict resolution process, and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state.